# ACCESS2013 - Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: ms-access, vba

I got en error while opening my form in access.
This code should be executed with the "OnOpen event" for that form. 
But im getting an error in my script.

```
Dim ThisDB As DAO.Database
    Set ThisDB = CurrentDb
    Dim d As DAO.Recordset
    Dim q As String
    q = "SELECT [tbl-apartner].[EMail] FROM [tbl-apartner] WHERE [tbl-apartner].[SID] = " & sid2 'sql query
    Set d = ThisDB.OpenRecordset(q, dbOpenDynaset)
    Dim Result As String
    Result = ""
    If d.EOF = False Or d.BOF = False Then 'if-else clause
        d.MoveFirst
        Do While Not d.EOF
            If Result <> "" Then Result = Result & "; "
            Result = Result & d!EMail
            d.MoveNext
          Loop
      End If
    d.Close
```

The faulty line is:

```
Set d = ThisDB.OpenRecordset(q, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: do a `debug.print q` before the openrecordset. My guess is that your `sid2`  is NULL

Comment: i did `MsgBox q`and the sid2 is not NULL. the output of `MsgBox q`is `SELECT [tbl-apartner].[EMail] FROM [tbl-apartner] WHERE [tbl-apartner].[SID] =  AKP`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

The Line

`q = "SELECT [tbl-apartner].[EMail] FROM [tbl-apartner] WHERE [tbl-apartner].[SID] = " & sid2`

was not correct.

```
q = "SELECT [tbl-apartner].[EMail] FROM [tbl-apartner] WHERE [tbl-apartner].[SID] = " & "'" & sid2 & "'"
```

The difference is:     `= " & "'" & sid2 & "'"`